# Rasa Chatbot cannot response to user input

Tags: python, rasa, rasa-core, rasa-x, nlu

I have using DIETClassifier for my entity extraction, and this is my pipeline:

```
pipeline:
  - name: SpacyNLP
    model: en_core_web_sm
  - name: SpacyTokenizer
  - name: CountVectorsFeaturizer
  - name: CRFEntityExtractor
  - name: DIETClassifier
    epochs: 200
    random_seed: 2
```

and this is example of intents that I have with entities in the nlu file:

```
version: "2.0"

nlu:
- intent: flight_search_intent
  examples: |
    - I want to [travel](Search_flight)
    - I want a travel [ticket](Search_flight)
    - I want a [flight](Search_flight) ticket
    - find a [flight](Search_flight) for me please
    - find a [flight](Search_flight) for me, please
    - Can you please find a [flight](Search_flight) ticket for me?
    - I want to book a [flight](Search_flight) ticket
    - I want to book a [ticket](Search_flight)
    - Can you please find a [flight](Search_flight) for me?
    - I want to book a [flight](Search_flight) asap
    - I want to book a [flight](Search_flight)
    - I am looking for a [flight](Search_flight)
    - find a [flight](Search_flight) for me
    - I wanna to [travel](Search_flight)
    - I need a [trip](Search_flight)

# 2) flight_search_intent_with_daeparture_and_destenation_cities_and_departure_date:
- intent: flight_search_intent_with_daeparture_and_destenation_cities_and_departure_date
  examples: |
    - I am looking for a [flight](Search_flight) from [Arrabury]{"entity": "city", "role": "departure"} to [Annaba]{"entity": "city", "role": "destination"} [Tomorrow](departure_date).
    - I want to book a [flight](Search_flight) from [Dammam]{"entity": "city", "role": "departure"} to [Jeddah]{"entity": "city", "role": "destination"} on [14/05/2022](departure_date).
    - I want to book a [flight](Search_flight) from [Berlin]{"entity": "city", "role": "departure"} to [San Francisco]{"entity": "city", "role": "destination"} on [30/1/2021](departure_date).
    - Can you please find a [flight](Search_flight) for me from [Al Madinah]{"entity": "city", "role": "departure"} to [Abha]{"entity": "city", "role": "destination"} on [3-4-2020](departure_date).
    - Book a [flight](Search_flight) from [Al Kharj]{"entity": "city", "role": "departure"} to [Bonthe]{"entity": "city", "role": "destination"} [Today](departure_date).
    - Book a [flight](Search_flight) from [Colombo]{"entity": "city", "role": "departure"} to [Paris]{"entity": "city", "role": "destination"} on [January,21st,2020](departure_date).
    - find a [flight](Search_flight) for me from [Berlin]{"entity": "city", "role": "departure"} to [San Francisco]{"entity": "city", "role": "destination"} on [January,21st,2020](departure_date).
    - I want to [fly](Search_flight) from [Berlin]{"entity": "city", "role": "departure"} to [San Francisco]{"entity": "city", "role": "destination"} on [17th January 2021](departure_date).
    - I wanna [trp](Search_flight) from [Berlin]{"entity": "city", "role": "departure"} to [San Francisco]{"entity": "city", "role": "destination"} on [17th January 2021](departure_date).
    - I need a [flight](Search_flight) from [Berlin]{"entity": "city", "role": "departure"} to [San Francisco]{"entity": "city", "role": "destination"} [Tomorrow](departure_date).
```

and this is example of my stories:

```
#1) Flight serch function stories:
- story: flight_search_function_story_1
  steps:
  - intent: greet
  - action: utter_greet
  - intent: flight_search_intent
  - action: utter_ask_about_trip_kind
  - intent: provide_round_trip
  - action: utter_ask_about_departure_city
  - intent: provide_departure_city
  - action: utter_ask_about_departure_date
  - intent: provide_date
  - action: utter_ask_about_destination_city
  - intent: provide_destination_city
  - action: utter_ask_about_return_date
  - intent: provide_date
  - action: utter_suitable choices
  - action: utter_something_else
  - intent: thanking
  - action: utter_welcome_thanks
  - intent: goodbye
  - action: utter_goodbye
```

and this is a part of my domain files where I listed all the intents, entities and the responses:

```
version: "2.0"

intents:
  - afternoon
  - morning
  - provide_date
  - nice_to_meet
  - provide_destination_city
  - get_Kind_of_cities
  - waiting
  - get_weather
  - greet
  - goodbye
  - goodnight
  - welcome_thanks
  - provide_one_way_trip
  - nice_to_talk
  - askingAboutDoingWithName
  - askingAboutDoingWithOutName
  - flight_search_intent_with_daeparture_and_destenation_cities_only
  - flight_search_with_destenation_only
  - flight_search_intent
  - provide_email
  - flight_search_intent_with_daeparture_and_destenation_cities_and_departure_date
  - provide_departure_city
  - evening
  - see_again
  - bot_challenge
  - provide_issue_deatils
  - user_waiting
  - well_done
  - sorry
  - get_Hoppies
  - thanking
  - flight_search_with_departure_only
  - provide_round_trip
  - provide_name
  - provide_phone_number
  - Connect_agent
  - place_to_visit

entities:
  - return_date
  - phone
  - provide_name
  - get_issue_details
  - weather_type
  - round_flight
  - report_issue
  - one_way_flight
  - hobby
  - return_decision
  - city_type
  - Search_flight
  - email
  - departure_date
  - name
  - city:
      roles:
        - departure
        - destination


responses:
  utter_greet:
  - text: "Hi I am Tickie! How can I help you?"

  utter_cheer_up:
  - text: "Here is something to cheer you up:"
    image: "https://i.imgur.com/nGF1K8f.jpg"

  utter_did_that_help:
  - text: "Did that help you?"
```

However, when I train my chatbot with `rasa train` command, and I tested it with `rasa shell` command, it gives only a response with the first input from the user(me) and then the responses stopped working! I am finding of the error and the solution for 2 weeks and I did not find it, this is an example:

[image]

can someone help me? or if I have any errors in my files that I mentioned above can someone tell me what is the errors? I followed the rasa documentation for the domain files and how to define the entities in the intents but I faced this problem, and all the explanasion I found on the internet is not with rasa 2.0 so I cannot know what is the problem

However, when I remove the entities form the domain file It has responses! but it is being like that:

[image]

it says add the entities to the domain file, and as I showed you before when I added them the responses stop working

Answer (score 1):

Unless the domain file does not show all the responses in your actual domain file, then your problem is that you haven't provided response text for most responses in your stories. You may have removed these accidentally when adding the entities.